# Making the y axis in HH:MM:SS instead of seconds in matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, time

I am using matplotlib (Python), I have y values in seconds (like 1000 seconds) and I want to display the ticks of y-axis in HH:MM:SS format. What is the simple solution to do that (with example).

Y is an integer list represents time duration in seconds

Sample code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y= np.array([1000,2000,4000,1000])
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Are you getting the yvalues from a dataframe? What does your code look like so far?

Comment: Lets say that y is a list of integers represents time duration in seconds

Comment: How do you want to convert `1000` to a time stamp? do you have a starting datetime you want to add these durations to?

Comment: Just simple conversion, for example 70 seconds is 00:01:10

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timedelta` function from the `datetime` module.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

y= np.array([1000,2000,4000,1000])
y_timedelta = [str(timedelta(seconds=int(s))) for s in y]
```

Result:

```
['0:16:40', '0:33:20', '1:06:40', '0:16:40']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Derek, however I have to use yticks and the full code working is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y= np.array([1000,3000,2000,4000])
y_timedelta = [str(timedelta(seconds=int(s))) for s in y]
plt.plot(y)
plt.yticks(y,y_timedelta)
plt.show()
```

This is output:
[image]

Comment: Please consider [accepting Derek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as it has solved your problem.